# Unrecognized attribute 'defaultAlgorithmSuite'

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm receiving an exception once I try to create a web service client instance. The message is "Unrecognized attribute 'defaultAlgorithmSuite'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive". The application is a MVC 5 over .NET Framework 4.5 being debugged in IIS Express from Visual Studio 2015. The same code is working in another application with same properties. The syntax verification in the Web.config is not recognizing the attributes in the tag security inside a the binding configuration of the service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MaxValueRecovery" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IMyService">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
                    authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    requireDerivedKeys="true"
                    includeTimestamp="true"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                    allowInsecureTransport="true"
                    enableUnsecuredResponse="true">
            <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://.../MyService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IMyService"
            contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" name="CustomBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What I'm missing or doing wrong? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally try to configure a custom binding as BasicHttpBinding. Move the

```
<binding name="CustomBinding_IMyService"> ... </binding>
```

block out of `<basicHttpBinding>` and under a `<customBinding>` parent:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MaxValueRecovery" ...>
        ...
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IMyService">
        ...
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

The security options you want to configure [are only supported on a custom binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731314%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).